# How to use completableFuture in testNG class

Tags: java, multithreading, testng

I want to run `CompletableFuture` in a TestNG class with `@Test` annotation.

Below is the code snippet, `recursionFuture` method is called recursively to do a certain task by the `main()` method. 
Now if I use `main()` as `public static void main(String[] args))` then everything works as desired. But when I used `main()` with `@Test` annotation then TestNG stops the execution in between and the whole task is not performed.

What should I do to make `@Test` to wait until all tasks are completed by `recursionFuture`?

I've to use `CompletableFuture` for async tasks and need to use `@Test` also.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
//public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException
    @Test // --> this logic of recursion with threads is problematic with testNG
    public static void main() throws FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException 
    {
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(new File("/Users/Pankaj/Desktop/Thread")));

        Method[] method = ConcurrencyPoC_CompletableFuture.class.getMethods();

        for(int i=0; i<method.length; i++)
        {
            if(method[i].getName().startsWith("task"))
            {
                TreeMap<Object, Object> m = new TreeMap<>();
                m.put(method[i].getName(), method[i]);
                m.put("status", new AtomicBoolean(true));

                taskmap.put(method[i].getName(), m);
            }
        }

        //submitting tasks 
        ExecutorService ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        CompletableFuture<?> [] arrayFutures = new CompletableFuture[3];
        recursionFuture(ex, arrayFutures);
    }


    public static String recursionFuture(ExecutorService ex, CompletableFuture<?> [] arrayFutures) 
    {
        try
        {

            //check if any of submitted future is completed - to be used in case of array 
            for(CompletableFuture<?> future : arrayFutures)
            {
                future = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> new ConcurrencyPoC_CompletableFuture().executeTask(), ex);

                //storing future in a final variable for further calculation
                final CompletableFuture<?> task = future;

                CompletableFuture.anyOf(task).thenRunAsync(() ->
                {
                    try {

                        //apply recursion only when future's output is not null, otherwise there will be hell lot of futures get created which 
                        //don't do anything just eating up memory and executing the else block of executeTask() method.
                        // Latest change, as soon as any task is free, create a new array of 1 size to do the next task
                        if(task.get() != null)
                            recursionFuture(ex, new CompletableFuture[1]);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                , ex);
            }

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return "ALl TASK COMPLETED";
    }
```

Comment: Why does TestNG stop? Do you have any stacktrace or error message? Could you set the TestNG versbosity to 10 and share the output?

Answer (score 0):

There is no correspondence between TestNG @Test annotation and your completable future.
The problem is in your tast.get() method. It should be blocking running threads until all completable futures are finished.

I use Completable Future in my tests and never ever I ever got into a problem with TestNG.

The problem is one of your future's finishes, and you return to the test method instead of waiting for all the futures. You should combine all your futures with thenApplyAsync() or compose() because your Future is final you are waiting only for one future. Plus you should not use CompletbleFuture.Any() because it returns to execution when the first future is complete.